# json-server returns HTTP 200 instead of 404 for query parameter filtered GET request, what is the best practice here & how can 404 be returned?

Tags: javascript, json, express, middleware, json-server

#### Context

Attempting to make a HTTP `GET` request for posts filtered by query parameter `authorId=x` where `x` may be a number that may not correspond to any post's `authorId`.

#### Problem

`json-server` unexpectedly returns HTTP `200` instead of HTTP `404` response when there are no posts with a matching `authorId` (i.e., an empty array is returned), how can this be changed to return `404`? Similarly, what would be the best API practice here, would it be to return an empty array with HTTP `400` as `json-server` already does or would returning the empty array with HTTP `404` be more clear for users?

I've looked at `jsonServer.rewriter` & `express` middleware (e.g., `json-server` documentation shows it can be configured with middleware such as `server.use(middlewares)`) but wanted to ask what the best approach would be here (useful resources/links would be appreciated here), e.g., with middleware, an option is sending `404` for an empty array but does `json-server` have an builtin ways to handle this or is there a better approach?

All constructive feedback is welcome, thanks.

#### Code

`db.json`:

```json
{
    "posts": [
        {
            "authorId": 0,
            "content": "Foo bar"
        },
    ],
}
```

Shell:

```sh
json-server --watch db.json
```

REST:

```
// Response status is expected HTTP 200.
GET http://localhost:5000/posts?authorId=0
```

This returns the user with HTTP `200` as expected:

```json
[
  {
      "authorId": 0,
      "content": "Foo bar",
  }
]
```

```
// Response status is unexpected HTTP 200 but 404 was expected since response body contains an empty array. This is the problem.
GET http://localhost:5000/posts?authorId=does_not_exist
```

This returns an empty array with HTTP `200`, which is possibly unexpected (uncertain on what the best practice is regarding filtered collections where there's no match, but what would be the best practice here & how can the status be changed to HTTP `400`:

```json
[]
```

Comment: Can you share the code ?

Comment: The code is in `db.json`. I've updated the question with the json-server command. This is using vanilla json-server so the server can be tested with `GET http://localhost:5000/posts?authorId=does_not_exist`

Comment: I mean the express code where you handle the GET requests.

Comment: I haven't written any handling for the requests (just running the server & making requests) as I'm using `json-server` as a minimal code mock API & was trying to see if `json-server` could be configured to return 404 when query parameters have no match

Comment: 404 means that the document wasn't found, not that the document is empty. The 200 is correct. I *strongly* advise you not to break HTTP.

Comment: @kindall good point, so in this case `json-server` is using the best practice & returning 404 with an empty array would be less clear for users? Regarding the question, how can `json-server` be configured to override it's builtin database routes (e.g., `/posts`) to return 404 instead of 200 (I understand now that this doesn't follow HTTP but wanted to know how this can be overridden)?

Comment: Yes, users will expect a successful request to have a 200 status. It is perfectly valid to request the posts of a user that hasn't made any posts; you just get an empty list. With regard to whether it's possible, dunno.

Comment: @kindall Thanks for explaining. Regarding overriding the builtin routes, `json-server`'s documentation shows it can be configured with middleware, which seems like it could provide the override although it's not clear how those builtins can be overridden to return a different HTTP status

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @kindall pointed out, probably ill-advised to return 404, but perhaps this is the existing behavior of the API you're mocking. You can return custom output - from docs: https://github.com/typicode/json-server#custom-output-example

```
// In this example we simulate a server side error response
router.render = (req, res) => {
  res.status(500).jsonp({
    error: "error message here"
  })
}
```

For your example, it would probably be something like (untested pseudo-code):

```
// In this example we return 404 for no content
router.render = (req, res) => {
  if (res.locals.data.posts.length < 1) {
    res.status(404).jsonp({
      error: "no posts"
    });
  } else {
    res.jsonp(res.locals.data);
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, this is close to what I was looking for when you filter the URL (i.e., `req.url.includes('/posts')`, I'm accepting this answer so it helps others facing the same issue :)

Comment: FYI If using typescript, `@types/json-server` (v0.14.4) results in a missing `.render`, where a workaround could be `(router as any).render`